# Can python lose memory (like c++ dynamic arrays and pointers) when working with arrays?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks

For instance:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3]
list_2 = [4, 5, 6]
list_3 = [7, 8, 9]

list_3 = list_2
list_2 = list_1
list_1 = [0, 0, 0]

# del list_3[:] # is this needed?

print(list_1) # [0, 0, 0]
print(list_2) # [1, 2, 3]
print(list_3) # [4, 5, 6]
```

is `list_3` initial value `[7, 8, 9]` lost in operating memory and needs to be deleted purposely with additional command like `del list_3[:]` like in c++ or is it deleted automatically by python interpreter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to deallocate that memory yourself. It will be handled automatically through the interpreter's [memory management](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html).